# Out of memory listbox-picture viewer

Tags: c#

Hey getting an out of memory issue when I click on an empty bitmap image.

```
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        //if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        //   try
        //   {
                pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:/folder/" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        //}

       //catch (NullReferenceException)
       //{

       //    MessageBox.Show("The image box is empty!");
       //}

    }
```

Ive attempted a try catch didnt work tho. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: your catch probably didn't work because you're catching a NullReferenceException, not the base Exception. Can't catch an OOM Exception with a NullRef Exception... by the way, you check for null with the if, why the catch of the NullRef anyway?

Comment: Have you tried just appending some string (like "mynameisbob") where you have  `listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`, just to narrow down what is causing you the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as an 'empty bitmap'.  You might have a bitmap that contains nothing but black or white pixels.  It needs just as much memory as one that has, say, a photo of the same size.  And is just as capable of generating an OOM exception when it is large.

Or because you clicked several times since you forgot to dispose the old one:

```
  if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
  pictureBox1.Image = null;
  pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(...);
```

There could also be something wrong with the image file format, perhaps one that GDI+ doesn't support.  That too generates OOM, unfortunately.  In case it is relevant: don't try to load a .txt file.